# How to get user anonymous id?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to get an anonymous id of the user, that which we define `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER` for it.
How can I get it?

this isn't successful:

```
UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP8:

```
UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID2", out anid)
```

WP7.x:

```
UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anid)
```

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for a WP8.1 WinRT solution, it's not possible on the WinRT platform (neither WP nor W8). See [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2ca0d5de-9db5-4349-839c-e01ff614ec6e/retrieve-computer-name-and-the-mac-id-of-the-device?forum=winappswithcsharp) for further details.